# Create a custom pick list like Contacts

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a table of "items" which is retrieved from the "internet". This table can  be pretty huge, and I need to put it in a Form.
I initially did it using a scrollView, however the list is too long, and "may" cause user frustration.

I have looked at the contact picker, this is a standard API and I would like to replicate something like that.

I have an Activity which shows the list of "items". Should I call this activity and handle the picking of the items from within here?
What im looking for if there is a class that I should inherit instead of doing it this way.

Comment: Edit: its a spinner not a scrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening the Items List view from the form, and setting the ItemClick event to add the item details into the Intent and send it back. Also, makes me use existing forms :)

Avoided creating something like a content provider as i do not want to share this with other applications

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) ?
If you have not, you should also try the corresponding tutorial ([Hello List View](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html))
and maybe this article about [increasing performances in List View](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html).

Comment: Yes I have tried that. So my question was: I have a spinner, but the amount of objects inside it could be potentially large (hundreds of them).
I have created a Listview activity of these objects. So my question was if i should leverage this activity when the user wants to choose one of the  items from the list of objects? Is there a best practice on how this should be done instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: what do you mean by "leverage this activity" ?

Comment: As in, in the CRUD form, the user presses a button to choose an item, and is presented with the List activity for that item. When they click on an item there, the list activity returns and the CRUD reads the item from the List Activity.
Im wondering if I am on the right track.